# offset is higher than number of produced records

Tags: apache-kafka

I have produced only two messages from Kafka Producer in purely empty topic, so there is no old messages in it. When I ran this command:

`%KAFKA_HOME%\bin\windows\kafka-consumer-groups.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group some-group`

I got this output:

| GROUP | TOPIC | PARTITION | CURRENT-OFFSET | LOG-END-OFFSET | LAG | CONSUMER-ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| some-group | some-topic | 0 | 4 | 4 | 0 | a9e083cb |
| some-group | some-topic | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | a9e083cb |
| some-group | some-topic | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | a9e083cb |

it tells me that there is the latest offset and its value is 4!
I really don't understand why it is as is. I produced only 2 records and because they stored in partition 0, offset had to be 0 and 1, or 1 and 2 but not 4!

I was not able to find out what is problem here.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Kafka include transactional producers, by default. This means some offsets will be transactional markers that a consumer can skip over during processing. So 2 records (running console producer twice) would also put two markers

Comment: thanks, could you provide a resource to understand more about that topic?